# Post data using ajax when click on a tag

Tags: php, ajax, post

ln php file I have a link like this:

```
<?php 
   echo "<a href='example.php add="'.$id.'"'>click</a>"
?>
```

And I need to send data in variable using Ajax if user click on the link but without get back data or move to another page.

Comment: You could try jQuery for ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to do it (Simply sending POST data):

```
var link_data = $('.link').data('data');
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://yourpage.com/page.php', //This is your url to open when he click the link
                type: "POST", //Its the method
                data: { link_data : link_data }, //Data to send

                success:function (data) {
                  console.log(data); //Logs the response from the URL to you console.
                }

            });
```

And heres your HTML part:

```
<?php 
   echo "<a class='link' href='example.php' data-data='{$id}'>click</a>";
?>
```